# which methodology should I use if I have nested if else's on a dataframe object

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create a new variable in my existing dataframe based on nested if else's. I tried using lambda but it gave me error. Since I am pretty new to Python which methodology should I use for nested if-else statements on a dataframe object?

Lambda function failed. 
I used the following for loop but that was a completely improper way as my dataset is really big.

This is a for loop which I have written to understand the logic. 'data'is my dataframe.

```
    for i,row in data.iterrows():
        if(row['Year1'] == row['Year2']):
           mnth_diff = row['mnth1'] - row['mnth2']
           if(mnth_diff > 0):
               data.loc[i,'new'] = 0
           elif(mnth_diff < 0):
               data.loc[i,'new'] = 1
           else:
               data.loc[i,'new'] = 0
       elif(row['Year1'] < row['Year2']):
           data.loc[i,'new'] = 0
       elif(row['Year1'] > row['Year2']):
           data.loc[i,'new'] = 1
```

I expect to write a code that is concise and should be time-efficient.

Comment: *"Lambda function failed."* Can you elaborate on this?  What exactly did you try?  You probably want to pull the if-else stuff into a function and then use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

Comment: I first split up the dataset into 3 based on the year logic. Then I applied lambda on the inner loop which worked fine. Finally i merged all the 3 dataframes into 1. But i want to avoid so much hassle and perform the logic in 1 step. Is this possible? Should i pass the entire dataset using the apply function?  Or should I use a map function here?

Comment: What's the desired result, for `data.loc[i,'new']` to be 1 if Year1/month1 is later than Year2/month2? That's just `data.loc[i,'new'] = int((row['Year1'], row['mnth1']) >= (row['Year2'], row['mnth2']))`.

Comment: I have already achieved the result but I want to understand how I can use a map or apply functions to implement this.

Comment: @Shreya you don't want to use `.apply`, that will be essentially as slow as your loop.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ohok! what is recommended then? I used something like this.          data['new'] = data[['year1','year2','mnth2','mnth1']]\
                           .apply(lambda x: calc_is_late(x['year1'],
                                                         x['year2'], 
                                                         x['mnth2'],  
                                                         x['mnth1']),axis=1)

Answer (score 0):

I got it finally! :)

```
  data['new'] = data[['year1','year2','mnth2','mnth1']]\
                           .apply(lambda x: calc_is_late(x['year1'],
                                                         x['year2'], 
                                                         x['mnth2'],  
                                                         x['mnth1']),axis=1)
```

Comment: if you write a complete answer including the  `calc_is_late` function  (and question including input data and desired result) people (me) could upvate your posts